# Material exclusivity to an object collection

Tags: materials, collections, color-management, duplicate

I have two collections, one is done with every object colored with the respective material, the other one is a duplicate of the first one but without the clothing.

[image]

The thing is because of the duplication, the materials duplicate too.

[image]

And i dont have a problem with editing every material copied, but i want to restrict the visibility of them, so that when i access to **Aban Fire_Fox** and select an object from the collection I just want to see the materials from that collection from the materials list, and when I access to **Aban Red_Panda** just want to see the list of materials exclusive for that collection, separately from the other one, instead of the whole listing including the ones from the copy.

Is there a way to exclusively see the materials for that collection in specific?